# Spring Webflux/Reactive in netty webserver returns 400 instead of 404 for missing path PARAM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using spring boot 2.6.6 and Spring Webflux 5.3.18 jar for handling my rest services in Reactive approach on Nettey server.

while validating the rest end point {{baseUrl}}/person/id,I am passing null/empty for path param "id"

```
{{baseUrl}}/person/
```

and expecting 404 but I am getting 400. the code not even reaching to GlobalExceptionHandler? Do i need to any additional logic using Filter to Handle the  400 and propagate to GlobalExceptionHandler? how to handle this?

**Interface:**

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<Person>> getPerson(
        @Parameter(name = "id", description = "The Person identifier.", required = true) @PathVariable("id") String id,
        @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
    );
```

**ExceptionHandler:**

```
 @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {


  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
    if (ex instanceof WebClientResponseException && ((WebClientResponseException)ex).getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND){
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            return writeErrorResponse(exchange, "NOT_FOUND");
        }

    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return writeErrorResponse(exchange, "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR");
  }

private Mono<Void> writeErrorResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange,String errorMessage) {
        DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory();
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(bufferFactory.wrap(errorMessage.getBytes())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is required(is set to required in your code), therefore you receive bad request (400) before even accessing function.
Try to set required = false on id then to manage response status.
By the way 'required = true' is set by default, so you do not need to write it.

Comment: I did tried  without required is true even then am getting 400 only.